# DB entity not recognized after Update Model from DataBase in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2017

I added some new columns to a table in Db and when I try to update Model from Database, my entity is not recognized. I have read something that is a bug from the 2017 version of VS. How can it be fixed?
I have encoutered the same problem with Refresh and with Add after I delete the tables from the edmx file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by Installing VS 2015. Apparently this version allows to Update from DB without errors.